# MySql Select Statement Failing

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, desktop-application

I am connecting to a MySql server. The MySql server is version 5.1.36. I am using Java SE with Eclipse Link for my JPA.

I have noticed that when I construct my class, I have to setup my SQL statement as

"`SELECT EMP.Index, EMP.Name FROM EMP`" instead of "`SEECT Index, Name FROM EMP`"

This is causing some issues since I have more complex objects that use the One to Many and Many to Many annotation.

Is it possible that I have a setup issue in my class or is this a limitation of the MySql database that I am using?

This class implementation will work with Many to Many annotation but not with my controller implementation

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Genre")
public class CGenre implements CGenericDomain, Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name="Index", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int itsIndex;

    @Column(name="Description")
    private String itsDescription;

    public CGenre()
    {
        // Do Nothing
    }

    public CGenre(String pDescription)
    {
        itsDescription = pDescription;
    }

    public void setItsIndex(int pIndex)
    {
        itsIndex = pIndex;
    }

    public int getItsIndex()
    {
        return itsIndex;
    }

    public String getItsDescription()
    {
        return itsDescription;
    }

    public void setItsDescription(String itsDescription)
    {
        this.itsDescription = itsDescription;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValue(String pObjName) {
        if (pObjName.equals("Description"))
        {
            return getItsDescription();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean setValue(String pObjName, Object pObjValue) {
        boolean result = false;
        if (pObjName.equals("Description"))
        {
            setItsDescription(pObjValue.toString());
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

This section of code, I can use it with my controller implementation

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Genre")
public class CGenre implements CGenericDomain, Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name="Genre.Index", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int itsIndex;

    @Column(name="Genre.Description")
    private String itsDescription;

    public CGenre()
    {
        // Do Nothing
    }

    public CGenre(String pDescription)
    {
        itsDescription = pDescription;
    }

    public void setItsIndex(int pIndex)
    {
        itsIndex = pIndex;
    }

    public int getItsIndex()
    {
        return itsIndex;
    }

    public String getItsDescription()
    {
        return itsDescription;
    }

    public void setItsDescription(String itsDescription)
    {
        this.itsDescription = itsDescription;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValue(String pObjName) {
        if (pObjName.equals("Description"))
        {
            return getItsDescription();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean setValue(String pObjName, Object pObjValue) {
        boolean result = false;
        if (pObjName.equals("Description"))
        {
            setItsDescription(pObjValue.toString());
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

My controller class

```
public class CGenreController extends CGenericController<CGenre> {

    @Override
    public List getAll() {
        return itsEntityManager.createQuery("Select m From CGenre m", CGenre.class).getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(CGenre pIn) {
        itsEntityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        itsEntityManager.merge((CGenre)pIn);
        itsEntityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    @Override
    public CGenre getValue(int pInt) {
        List<CGenre> result = itsEntityManager.createQuery("select m from CGenre m where m.Index = ?1")
        .setParameter(1, pInt).getResultList();
        if (result.size() > 1)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return result.get(0);
    }
}
```

My persistence file

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
  version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">

```
<class>com.movie.domain.CMovieType</class>
<class>com.movie.domain.CGenre</class>
<class>com.movie.domain.CDiscType</class>
 <class>com.movie.domain.CActor</class>
 <class>com.movie.domain.CMovie</class>

<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://xxxxx/Movies" />
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="xxxxx" />
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="xxxxx" />
</properties>
```

Error message I am getting during execution:

> Internal Exception:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Index,
>   Description FROM Genre' at line 1 Error Code: 1064 Call: SELECT Index,
>   Description FROM Genre Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=CGenre
>   sql="SELECT Index, Description FROM Genre")

My current work around will be to split out all domains for individual and multiple annotation. This will increase my maintenance work and (in my personal opinion) unsatisfactory code.

You thoughts on what I am doing wrong will help out a lot.

Thanks, community.

Comment: Which call is resulting in that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`index` is a reserved keyword in SQL. Don't name your column `index`.

Also, your second query is invalid. You really need to realize your queries are not SQL queries, but JPQL queries. And JPQL never uses column names. It uses the names of your annotated fields. So the query should be:

```
select m from CGenre m where m.itsIndex = ?1
```

And this should then make you realize how your non-standard naming conventions are awful. If you followed the standard ones, the class would be named `Genre` and the property would be named `index`, and the query and the code would then be much more readable, using real English names:

```
select g from Genre g where g.index = ?1
```

Comment: What is the standard name convention for db columns?

Comment: There is none. But what I talk about in my answer is the convention for Java fields. Not for database columns.

Comment: Yeah, I have been told that could times about my Java fields by college professors. It is something that I picked up in my career and have not dropped. Again, thanks for pointing out that Index is a keyword. I have a copy of they keywords and checking to ensure I don't have any conflicts.